# Swiftui form re-using at multiple place not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, forms, swiftui

I have created model and using that model Im modify variable data at multiple places I can modify and enter data succesfully in FirstView. I could able to modify data in the SecondView. In SecondView, Whatever content I type in the textfield it goes away instanly (in short not allowing to enter data and ofc no error shown)

I want to know am i using proper object variable to call model every time

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var age = ""
    }


// Using at one place
struct FirstView : View {

    @StateObject var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("", text: self.$MainViewModel.name) 
        TextField("", text: self.$MainViewModel.age) 
    }
}
}

// ReUsing same at another place

struct SecondView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("", text: self.$MainViewModel.name) 
        TextField("", text: self.$MainViewModel.age) 
    }
}
}
```

I have tried using @EnvironmentObject using at both view but doesnt work either here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
```

To

```
@EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel : MainViewModel
```

Make sure you are injecting in the parent view

```
.environmentObject(mainViewModel)
```

Comment: I have added in parent view.

Comment: Thanks for input on it. But getting this error in FirstView swiftfile though added in parent view .environmentObject(mainViewModel).  Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type MainViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for MainViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Comment: @EN_Tech like I said you have to inject it in the parent view

Comment: Thanks @loren ipsum. I was able to do it

Comment: @EN_Tech if you don’t mind can you click on the green check mark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

@lorem ipsum explain the question perfectly. I am just converting his comments into working code. Please have look. This will make you more clear about your issue about injecting from parent.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct StackOverflowApp: App {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                FirstView()
                    .environmentObject(MainViewModel())
            }
        }
    }
}



import SwiftUI


class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var age = ""
}


// Using at one place
struct FirstView : View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel : MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("", text: $mainViewModel.name)
                TextField("", text: $mainViewModel.age)
            }
            
            NavigationLink {
                SecondView()
                    .environmentObject(mainViewModel)
                // Either you can inject new or same object from child to parent. @lorem ipsum
//                    .environmentObject(MainViewModel())
            } label: {
                Text("Second View")
            }
        }
    }
}

// ReUsing same at another place

struct SecondView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel : MainViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("", text: $mainViewModel.name)
            TextField("", text: $mainViewModel.age)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this proper working solution and clean

Comment: Thanks to the Qazi and loren ipsum of input on this